# My computer freezes randomly, what can I do to fix this?

Tags: freeze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I troubleshoot a Windows 7 freeze or slowness?](https://superuser.com/questions/205298/how-do-i-troubleshoot-a-windows-7-freeze-or-slowness)

I tried to run check disk and it retuned no errors or bad sectors. I also run CCleaner and also no effect.

What else can I do to determine the problem and solve it?

OS: Windows 7

I installed different application for data recovery and uninstalled them.
Also I uninstalled any application that I installed recently

EDIT:
I need to do hard reset to get out of freeze state

EDIT1:
In safe mode it doesn't freeze

**EDIT2:(Solved)**
I disabled all the services and the programs that loads on startup accept for security & microsoft services. My computer worked all night without freezing!

Comment: First, figure out what kind of freeze you have. Is the OS stopping, or is the CPU stopping, or ... ? Then search the internet to match the symptoms that you have with possible causes.

Comment: Can you please add more info. Add information like applications you recently installed, operating system, antivirus/anti-spyware and etc.

Comment: How old is your computer?

Comment: Maybe you should install an operating system?  (I assume that if you had one installed you'd have specified what it was.)

Comment: Also see: [How to diagnose computer lockups and freezes?](http://superuser.com/questions/220678/how-to-diagnose-computer-lockups-and-freezes)

Answer (score 1):

1) You should [look into windows event log](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/What-information-appears-in-event-logs-Event-Viewer) and see if there any errors.

2) You should [check memory](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/715-memory-diagnostics-tool.html) and [harddrive for bad sectors](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Check-your-hard-disk-for-errors).

3) If 1 and 2 isn't diagnose the reason, you should install "Windows performance toolkit" from "Windows SDK" (download Windows SDK installer, the performance toolkit is one of the installation options). Read manual for xperf. Run it with circular buffer and when next freeze will happen, you could see what happened to your system.

After installing xperf, open cmd in administrative mode and run command:

```
xperf -on latency -maxfile 256 -filemode circular
```

and wait until the next freeze. Right after the freeze write into the console

```
xperf -d trace.etl 
xperf trace.etl
```

Press "yes" to open file in a trace viewer. Put the pictures here. Or read xperf help.

Comment: How do I check 1 and 2?

Comment: I Added links to the post

Comment: Can you give me more details about 3? I didn't understand it.

Comment: After my system hangs I can not do anything only hard reset.
So I can't write into the console the lines you wrote...

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://superuser.com/questions/220678/how-to-diagnose-computer-lockups-and-freezes) describes similar freeze-ups. Essentially, since almost everything in most PCs is connected to a single bus, it could be anything, including a bad card, overheating, memory error, and even a faulty USB plug or cord on some older systems. Yes, malware can sometimes cause a denial of service by hogging all available resources, but usually the only thing that can cause a complete system lock-up/freeze is the video card. Everything else generates some kind of error log, message, reboot, or blue or black screen, in my experience. I have even opened up a PC to find bugs or mice living in there causing random shorts. A loose screw. If the logs, memory, and disk checks don't show anything consistent and the disk is OK as you say it's probably hardware.

Sometimes a BIOS and various firmware updates will fix incompatibilities with hardware. They can also make bricks if you do it wrong, so beware.

Answer (score 0):

With all the viruses and malware\spyware\adware floating around the Internet your problem could be caused by many things besides the hard drive needing a CHKDSK. Some of these cause your CPU to run to 100% which then makes it freeze, or so it would seem.

Do a complete virus scan and clean. Then run [Malware Bytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org) or [SpyBot S&D](http://www.safer-networking.org/index2.html) to make sure there isn't anything else (malware/spyware/adware) messing with your system. A free online scan at [eSet](http://www.eset.com/us/online-scanner/) just to make sure its all gone might be a good idea.

Once you are sure your system is clean, then start looking at hardware issues.